# What is {G,T} in group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Herstein in his book "Topics in algebra", P70 says that

> If $G$ is a group, $Τ$ an automorphism of order $r$ of $G$ which is not an inner automorphism, pick a symbol $x$ and consider all elements $x^ig, i = 0, ±1, ±2, ...; g \in G$ subject to $x^ig = x^{i'}g'$ if and only if $i \equiv i' \mod r$ and $g=g'$ and $x^{-1}g^ix=gT^i$ for all $i$. This way we obtain a larger group $\{G,T\}$ , $G$ is normal in $\{G,T\}$ and $\{G,T\}/G$ is isomorphic to group generated by $T$, that is, it is isomorphic to cyclic group of order $r$.

i can't get what $\{G,T\}$  is, by this description. For example i do not know where does $x$ come from etc. It will be a big help if I can get a name for this group $\{G,T\}$, or other reference (online or book).

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the underlying set is just $\mathbb Z_r \times G$.

Comment: The phrase to google is "semidirect product".

Comment: The underlying set is $\mathbb{Z}_r\times G$ but the group operation is quite different.